# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes upon opening browser using wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, freeze

I recently bought a usb adapter to connect to wifi. The device name is tenda and the built driver name is `mt7601Usta.ko`, that is supposed to be a rip off of rt2870 driver.

It is able to detect wifi and to connect.

Just when I open chromium or firefox, ubuntu freezes. Keyboard, mouse doesn't work and I have to reboot.

If I connect lan cable I am able to surf internet without any problem so it looks like some kind of wifi problem.

my setup :

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dual boot with windows 7.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux nikhil 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

All the solutions related to freezing of ubuntu is related to older versions of ubuntu such as 11.10.

I am new to this forum and probably missed some vital information so please reply if you need more information.